# How to check if DirectedSparsedGraph contains an Edge between Nodes having those 2 nodes?

Tags: java, graph, distance, jung, knn

I am trying to implement creation of kNN graph using jung library. I have came to a moment where I need to check if a link between 2 `Node`s already exists in the graph.

My code so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
  for (Iterator<Node> it1 = mGraph.getVertices().iterator(); it1.hasNext();) {
    Node n1 = (Node) it1.next();
    double minDistance = 9999999;
    Node toConnect = null;

    for (Iterator<Node> it2 = mGraph.getVertices().iterator(); it2.hasNext();) {
      Node n2 = (Node) it2.next();
      double currDistance = this.getDistance(n1, n2);
      if( currDistance < minDistance &&  
          mGraph.containsEdge( /* WHAT HERE */ ) ){
        minDistance = currDistance;
        toConnect = n2; 
      }   
    }   
    mGraph.addEdge(new Link(), n1, toConnect, EdgeType.DIRECTED);   
  }           
}
```

I do not know how to do this since there is only one constructor for `Link` without any parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isNeighbor() works for undirected graphs or if you don't care how the two nodes are connected (that is, which way the existing edge, if any, goes) .  For a directed Graph you probably want isPredecessor().

Comment: I have used `isPredecessor()` in the end. Thanks for pointing out that  `isNeigbor()` is for undirected only.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that I can do this the following way (maybe someone will comment if it's efficient and ok)

```
mGraph.isNeighbor(n1, n2)
```

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have two nodes, n1 and n2, and your graph is called mGraph you can simply create a new method:

```
public boolean existsLink(Node n1, Node n2) {
  return mGraph.getNeighbors(n1).contains(n2);
}
```

If it returns true, it means the edge exists; returns false if the edge does not exist. Please note that mGraph.getNeighbors(n1) is a Collection.

You could also use the method: mGraph.containsEdge(E edge). But I don't know wich type is your E edge, and which methods it has.

Comment: Checking to see whether a particular edge is present is only useful if the way that an edge object is created incorporates the nodes somehow (not generally needed in JUNG and not what's happening here), so that you can create the edge object and then ask whether it's present.  Graph.isPredecessor() is meant for this.

Comment: Yes I know but, with the information he gave this is the only solution I can see. If he had told us wich kind of object are his edges I would have suggested that option....